# Xamarin WebView.CanGoBack and CanGoForward always return false after page loaded

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new at Xamarin.Forms, so excuse me if I don't use the correct words. I created a solution called "WebBrowser" in order to create a simple mobile browser; at the moment I'm working on the common files *MainPage.xaml* and *MainPage.xaml.cs*, and I'm testing the code on an **Android 5.1** smartphone.
I use **Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 15.5.4**.

In *MainPage.xaml* I specified the following code

```
<Button Text="Back"
        x:Name="backButton"
        IsEnabled="False"
        Clicked="previousPage"/>

<Button Text="Next"
        x:Name="nextButton"
        IsEnabled="False"
        Clicked="nextPage"/>

<WebView x:Name="appWebView"
         Source="https://www.google.com/"
         Navigating="onLoadingPage"
         Navigated="onPageLoaded"/>
```

so when a page is loaded, the method `onPageLoaded()` is called.

This method contains the following code

```
private void onPageLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (appWebView.CanGoBack)
        backButton.IsEnabled = true;
    else
        backButton.IsEnabled = false;

    if (appWebView.CanGoForward)
        nextButton.IsEnabled = true;
    else
        nextButton.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

in order to enable/disable the "arrow" buttons when the user can/can't go to the previous/next page.

In this situation `appWebView.CanGoBack` and `appWebView.CanGoForward` **always** return false, even when it should be true. But if I keep the buttons enabled and I check their values when the user clicks one of the buttons, both return the correct value.

Why doesn't it work inside `onPageLoaded()` method?

Comment: It seems like the event is being raised before the property is effectively changed. Can you share the `backbutton` and `nextButton` creation code? Maybe there is another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza code updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the exact answer to what you asked for, but you can use the Bindings resource to do such a thing. Like this:

```
<Button Text="Back"
        x:Name="backButton"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CanGoBack, Source={Reference appWebView}}"
        Clicked="previousPage"/>

<Button Text="Next"
        x:Name="nextButton"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CanGoForward, Source={Reference appWebView}}"
        Clicked="nextPage"/>

<WebView x:Name="appWebView"
         Source="https://www.google.com/"
         Navigating="onLoadingPage"/>
```

It's simpler. Take a look at [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) if you wanna know more about bindings on Xamarin.Forms.

Thus you can get rid of the `onPageLoaded` event handler if it exists only for this.

I hope it helps.

[EDIT] Spelling Correction `CanGoForward`