# Xamarin Forms WebView cache: GoBack() doesn't call Navigating event

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As I previously said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690492/xamarin-webview-cangoback-and-cangoforward-always-return-false-after-page-loaded), I'm new at Xamarin.Forms and I'm developing a cross-platform web browser with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.4. I'm debugging on an Android 5.1 smartphone.

In my layout there's a `WebView` and two `Buttons` to go back/forward.

```
<Button Image="backarrowdisabled.png"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="backButton"
        IsEnabled="False"
        Clicked="previousPage">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button"
                     Binding="{Binding CanGoBack, Source={Reference appWebView}}"
                     Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Image" Value="backarrowdisabled.png" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button"
                     Binding="{Binding CanGoBack, Source={Reference appWebView}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Image" Value="backarrow.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>


<Button Image="nextarrowdisabled.png"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="5"
        x:Name="nextButton"
        IsEnabled="False"
        Clicked="nextPage">
        /* triggers */   
</Button>

<WebView Grid.Row="3"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
         x:Name="appWebView"
         Source="https://www.google.it/"
         Navigating="onPageLoading"
         Navigated="onPageLoaded"/>
```

As you can see there are two methods to manage `Navigating` and `Navigated` events, which are

```
private void onPageLoading(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    URLEntry.Text = e.Url;      //Entry where I can see the page URL
    //other code
}

private void onPageLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code       
}
```

When I click on a link or something like that in my `WebView` everything works correctly, but when I have to go back/forward in my history the `Entry` doesn't update the URL to the previous/next one. It seems it doesn't even call the `onPageLoading` method, but the `WebView` loads the page.

These are the methods called by the `Buttons`

```
private void previousPage (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    appWebView.GoBack();
}

private void nextPage (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    appWebView.GoForward();
}
```

Is it a `WebView` bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**: I think the pages are cached, is there a way to make it not do it?

Comment: Did you check if it's triggering the `onPageLoaded` event?

Comment: Anyway, your `Entry.Text` could be bound to `WebView.Source` either. Like this: `<Entry x:Name="URLEntry" Text="{Binding Source, Source={x:Reference appWebView}}" ... />`.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I've checked right now, it's triggering `onPageLoaded` but not `onPageLoading`

Comment: Hmn... It seems there's a cache working behind the hood, I didn't find anything about it in the official documentation, but it's understandable once the component provides the `GoBack` and `GoForward` methods. To keep your thinking line, just change the signature of the `onPageLoaded` method to `(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)` and try setting the `URLEntry.Text = e.Url;` inside it instead of `onPageLoading` as a workaround. (Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza ok, thank you a lot. Now I noticed I have the same problem when I manually define `appWebView.Source` in my .cs file, that is it's triggering `onPageLoaded` but not `onPageLoading`... When I click on a link in my WebView I don't have these problems

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do, is to create another event handler for the `WebView`'s `PropertyChanged` or `PropertyChanging` event. There, you can check to see if the `Source` property was changed; If so, you can update the `TextView` with the new source. (I'm not sure exactly, but it seems like whe navigating back or forward, the `Navigating` event does not get called, possibly because the page is already cached?)

See here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.OnPropertyChanged/p/System.String/

So your code can look like

```
<WebView x:Name="MyWebView" PropertyChanged="OnWebViewPropertyChanged" />
```

and then your code behind:

```
private void OnWebViewPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == WebView.SourceProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        URLEntry.Text = MyWebView.Source.ToString(); // May need to check this
    }
}
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 100:22. Method OnWebViewPropertyChanged does not have the correct signature

Comment: The same if I declare the method as `protected override void` (as it's written on the page you linked)

Comment: @mara6399 I updated the answer to show the correct method signature. I guess Xamarin's documentation is a little off.

Comment: Now it works perfectly, just edit with `(appWebView.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url` instead of `MyWebView.Source.ToString()`